# Laravel Update Single row attached with a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

[database structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tReE1.png) i am creating a loan repayment system with laravel and whenever i repay a loan i want to update the "principal repaid derived" and "interest repaid derived" for the first due repayment attached to the loan id

if the amount repaid is less than or equal to the "principal" it update the "principal repaid derived" with the amount repaid and then update "outstanding" with ("total due" - "principal repaid") for that first due payment

if the amount repaid is less than or equal to the "total due" then it update "principal repaid derived" with the "principal" , update "interest repaid derived" with ("total due" - amount repaid) then update "outstanding" with ("total due" - "principal repaid " - "interest repaid") for the first due repayment

if the amount repaid is greater  than "total due" for that first repayment then update the "principal repaid " with principal , "interest repaid" with "interest" then go ahead to the next repayment with amount repaid as ("amount repaid" - "total due ") then loop over till last repayment

my code output update all repayment associated with the id and thats not what i want
if there is a better way to do this please guide me

---------------------------my controller---------------------------

```
$loan = DB::table('tbl_loans')
                    ->where('loan_id', $loan_id)
                    ->get();

                $repayment_schedules = DB::table('tbl_loan_repayment_schedule')
                    ->where('loan_id', $loan_id)
                    ->get();

                $original_transactions = DB::table('tbl_loan_transactions')
                    ->where('loan_id', $loan_id)
                    ->whereIn('loan_transaction_type_id', [3, 8])
                    ->orderBy('loan_transaction_id', 'asc')
                    ->get();

                $transactions = DB::table('tbl_loan_transactions')
                    ->where('loan_id', $loan_id)
                    ->whereIn('loan_transaction_type_id', [3, 8])
                    ->orderBy('loan_transaction_id', 'asc')
                    ->get();

                foreach ($repayment_schedules as &$repayment_schedule) {

                    $r_schedule = array();

                    $r_schedule['total_due'] = ($repayment_schedule->principal - $repayment_schedule->principal_repaid_derived)
                         +
                        ($repayment_schedule->interest - $repayment_schedule->interest_repaid_derived);

                    $r_schedule['principal_repaid_derived'] = 0;
                    $r_schedule['interest_repaid_derived'] = 0;

                    DB::table('tbl_loan_repayment_schedule')
                        ->where('loan_id', $loan_id)
                        ->orderBy('due_date', 'asc')
                        ->update($r_schedule);
                }

                foreach ($transactions as &$transaction) {
                    $amount = $transaction->amount;
                    $principal_repaid_derived = 0;
                    $interest_repaid_derived = 0;

                    //loop through repayment schedules
                    foreach ($repayment_schedules as &$repayment_schedule) {
                        if ($amount <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        $principal = $repayment_schedule->principal - $repayment_schedule->principal_repaid_derived;
                        $interest = $repayment_schedule->interest - $repayment_schedule->interest_repaid_derived;
                        $due = $principal + $interest;

                        if ($due <= 0) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        //allocate the payment

                        //principal
                        $schedule = array();
                        if ($amount >= $principal && $principal > 0) {
                            $schedule['principal_repaid_derived'] = $repayment_schedule->principal_repaid_derived + $principal;
                            $principal_repaid_derived = $principal_repaid_derived + $principal;
                            $amount = $amount - $principal;

                        } elseif ($amount < $principal && $principal > 0) {
                            $schedule['principal_repaid_derived'] = $repayment_schedule->principal_repaid_derived + $amount;
                            $principal_repaid_derived = $principal_repaid_derived + $amount;
                            $amount = 0;
                        }
                        //interest
                        if ($amount >= $interest && $interest > 0) {
                            $schedule['interest_repaid_derived'] = $repayment_schedule->interest_repaid_derived + $interest;
                            $interest_repaid_derived = $interest_repaid_derived + $interest;
                            $amount = $amount - $interest;
                        } elseif ($amount < $interest && $interest > 0) {

                            $schedule['interest_repaid_derived'] = $repayment_schedule->interest_repaid_derived + $amount;
                            $interest_repaid_derived = $interest_repaid_derived + $amount;
                            $amount = 0;

                        }

                        if (($repayment_schedule->principal - $repayment_schedule->principal_repaid_derived) + ($repayment_schedule->interest - $repayment_schedule->interest_repaid_derived) <= 0) {

                            $schedule['paid_by_date'] = $transaction->submitted_on;

                        }

                        $schedule['total_due'] = ($repayment_schedule->principal - $repayment_schedule->principal_repaid_derived) + ($repayment_schedule->interest - $repayment_schedule->interest_repaid_derived);

                        DB::table('tbl_loan_repayment_schedule')
                            ->where('loan_id', $loan_id)
                            ->orderBy('due_date', 'asc')
                            ->update($schedule);

                        // dd($schedule);

                        if ($amount <= 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    $tranx = array();

                    $tranx['principal_repaid_derived'] = $principal_repaid_derived;
                    $tranx['interest_repaid_derived'] = $interest_repaid_derived;

                    DB::table('tbl_loan_transactions')
                        ->where('loan_id', $loan_id)
                        ->whereIn('loan_transaction_type_id', [3, 8])
                        ->orderBy('loan_transaction_id', 'asc')
                        ->update($tranx);
                    if ($amount <= 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                // echo json_encode($transactions);
                $unchanged_transactions = [];
                foreach ($original_transactions as $key) {
                    array_push($unchanged_transactions, [
                        $key->loan_transaction_id,
                        $key->loan_id,
                        $key->payment_type_id,
                        $key->amount,
                        $key->principal_repaid_derived,
                        $key->interest_repaid_derived,
                        $key->submitted_on,
                    ]);
                }
                $changed_transactions = [];
                $count = 1;
                foreach ($transactions as $key) {
                    array_push($changed_transactions, [
                        $key->loan_transaction_id,
                        $key->loan_id,
                        $key->payment_type_id,
                        $key->amount,
                        $key->principal_repaid_derived,
                        $key->interest_repaid_derived,
                        $key->submitted_on,
                    ]);
                    $count++;
                }

                function compare_multi_dimensional_array($array1, $array2)
                {
                    $result = array();
                    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
                        if (!is_array($array2) || !array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
                            $result[$key] = $value;
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (is_array($value)) {
                            $recursiveArrayDiff = compare_multi_dimensional_array($value, $array2[$key]);
                            if (count($recursiveArrayDiff)) {
                                $result[$key] = $recursiveArrayDiff;
                            }
                            continue;
                        }
                        if ($value != $array2[$key]) {
                            $result[$key] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                    return $result;
                }

                $transactions_to_be_updated = compare_multi_dimensional_array($changed_transactions, $unchanged_transactions);

                foreach ($transactions_to_be_updated as $key => $value) {
                    $transaction = $unchanged_transactions[$key];
                    // dd($transactions_to_be_updated);
                }
                // dd($transactions_to_be_updated);
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug why this code does not work as expected? Sounds like any of the statements to load a record does not select the record that should be updated? Additionally, please consider restructuring your application - this is heavy business logic which should not be part of a controller, but of a seperate service

Comment: Would you give some explanation about the two-column?. 1) principal_repaid_derived 2) interest_repaid_derived. What are the purposes of the uses of these two columns?

Comment: @NicoHaase i have tried to debug and i just couldnt find the problem
it keeps updating the whole record instead of the first due payment

sorry for the late reply i forgot to refresh

Comment: @AshifulIslamPrince the principal repaid derived is where the amount paid should be if the repaid amount is equal to the principal

more or less the place that contains the amount paid

Comment: @NicoHaase i will probably use the service method in the next version

Comment: @AshifulIslamPrince please read my post for better clarification